# Mysql stored procedure skipping inserts

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure that I have developed and well tested. Now that it has been deployed commercially , it fails to insert some records but still returns expected results. No errors or warnings are thrown.

It can miss 3 inserts per 150 calls.

What could I be missing.

Comment: You missed to add the code to your question

Comment: i guess something is wrong your code that's why it is happening that. But how could we know without seing the code?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is continue to execute your query until any error occurs. But after error if they are have correct statement continue to execute. I think within the errors skips the three records.

Comment: Hi guys I have also notice something else. I made a service a to call the procedure after ever second. I also inluded insert statements on every condition so so as to have a log and get where thins procedure breaks. I also include a query to fetch the max() id of the record inserted.  When It fails to insert on the main record it also fails to insert on the logs table .Keep in mind the procedure is not a transaction. However I have notice the max() query returns a record which does not exist in the table. My take is it got it from the index table but failed to commit.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, its being called by a java service which captures any mysql error thrown but it does no throw one. Not even a warning.

Here is the code:

```
    DELIMITER $$

USE `parkinglot`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `process_acard`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`jeremiah`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `process_acard`(_station INT(4),_cardno VARCHAR(10),_baloncard DOUBLE,_transam FLOAT,_lane VARCHAR(50),_lpn VARCHAR(8),_vehcat INT(4),_fimagepath VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
   DECLARE bool_code VARCHAR(6);
   DECLARE error_code VARCHAR(6);
   DECLARE info_msg VARCHAR(6);
   DECLARE message_string VARCHAR(255);
   DECLARE return_value FLOAT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE master_or_blocked INTEGER(2);
   DECLARE is_blacklisted INT(2);
   DECLARE stn_name VARCHAR(50);
   DECLARE stn_type VARCHAR(20);
   DECLARE mysite VARCHAR (4);
   DECLARE myzone INTEGER (4);
   DECLARE entry_zone INTEGER (4);
   DECLARE merch_agent VARCHAR(11);
   DECLARE sea_reg_lpn INTEGER(2) DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE sea_ent_lpn INTEGER(2) DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE sea_lpn VARCHAR(10);
   DECLARE ent_lpn VARCHAR(10);
   DECLARE sea_validfrom DATETIME;
   DECLARE sea_validto DATETIME;
   DECLARE op_date DATE;
   DECLARE sea_block_status INT(2);
   DECLARE sea_exists INT(10);
   DECLARE tea_exists INT(10);
   DECLARE location INT(4);
   DECLARE ta_rif INT(4);
   DECLARE ent_device VARCHAR(50);
   DECLARE error_sev VARCHAR(50);
   DECLARE _limagepath VARCHAR(50);
   DECLARE time_in DATETIME;
   DECLARE time_now DATETIME;
   DECLARE raw_duration TINYINT;
   DECLARE days_spent TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE fd_fee FLOAT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE fee1 FLOAT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE fee2 FLOAT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE dow1 TINYINT;
   DECLARE dow2 TINYINT;
   DECLARE total_fee FLOAT;
   DECLARE cardrec INT;
   DECLARE shift_string VARCHAR(100);
   DECLARE myshift VARCHAR(100);
   DECLARE pass_key VARCHAR(5);
   DECLARE amount_charged DOUBLE;
   DECLARE pay_state INT(4);
   DECLARE lipa_activity INT(4);
   DECLARE ent_dex VARCHAR(200);
   DECLARE exit_dex VARCHAR(200);
   DECLARE acq_entry_dex VARCHAR(200);
   DECLARE acq_trans_dex VARCHAR(200);
   DECLARE pending_value INTEGER(10);
   DECLARE pending INT(1) DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE pending_id INT(10) UNSIGNED;
   DECLARE use_entry_zone INT;
   DECLARE sarit_apb INT(1);
   DECLARE char_amount VARCHAR(100);
   DECLARE useful_transtype INT(1);
   DECLARE sarit_avg_amt DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE card_trans_type INT(2);
   DECLARE confirm_insert INT(2);
   DECLARE newest_record_id INT(8);
   DECLARE event VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE story VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE lastinsert BIGINT;
   DECLARE check_entry_bal INT(1);
   DECLARE min_entry_bal INT(8);



IF(CHAR_LENGTH(_cardno)<9 OR CHAR_LENGTH(_station)<1)THEN
    SET bool_code='FALSE';
    SET error_code='ER225';
    SET info_msg='MS225';
ELSE
    IF (ISNULL(_vehcat) OR CHAR_LENGTH(_vehcat)<1) THEN SET _vehcat=1; END IF;

    SELECT get_lpn_path(_lpn,NOW()) INTO _limagepath;

    SELECT station_name,station_type,site_no,site_zone,commercial_id FROM site_config
    WHERE station_id=_station INTO stn_name,stn_type,mysite,myzone,merch_agent;

    INSERT INTO acard_temp_log(`card_no`,`card_event`) VALUES(_cardno,stn_type);/*Tell the real story*/

    SELECT card_status FROM special_acards WHERE card_no=_cardno LIMIT 1 INTO master_or_blocked;/*1-master,2-blocked*/

    IF(master_or_blocked=2)THEN

        SET event='SPECIAL';

        INSERT INTO bbc_attempts(`card_no`,`trans_date`,`station_name`,`lane_name`,`stationid`)VALUES
                    (_cardno,NOW(),stn_name,_lane,_station);

        SET bool_code='FALSE';
        SET error_code='ER244';
        SET info_msg='MS244';

    ELSEIF(master_or_blocked=1)THEN

        SET event='SPECIAL';

        INSERT INTO mastercard_transactions(`card_no`,`trans_date`,`station_name`,`lane_name`,`stationid`)VALUES
                    (_cardno,NOW(),stn_name,_lane,_station);

        SET bool_code='TRUE';
        SET error_code='ER000';
        SET info_msg='MS245';

    ELSE 
    /*we continue after realising card is neither blocked nor a mastercard.Now we check if it is globally blacklisted */
        SELECT blocked FROM acard_blacklist WHERE card_no=_cardno LIMIT 1 INTO is_blacklisted;



        IF(is_blacklisted=1)THEN

            SET event='SPECIAL';

            INSERT INTO bbc_attempts(`card_no`,`trans_date`,`station_name`,`lane_name`,`stationid`)VALUES
                        (_cardno,NOW(),stn_name,_lane,_station);

            SET bool_code='FALSE';
            SET error_code='ER229';
            SET info_msg='MS229';


        ELSE



        /*mhh.Not blacklist. Lets now check if it is a seasonal card with all checks*/

            SELECT `s_id`,`validfrom`,`validto`,`blocked`,car_reg FROM seasonal_cards WHERE card_no=_cardno AND site_no=mysite INTO sea_exists,sea_validfrom,sea_validto,sea_block_status,sea_lpn ;
            IF(sea_exists>=1)THEN/*this is a seasonlacard*/

                SELECT SQL_CACHE setting_validity FROM global_settings WHERE setting_name='seasonal_LPNI' AND site_applicable=mysite INTO sea_ent_lpn;
                SELECT SQL_CACHE setting_validity FROM global_settings WHERE setting_name='seasonal_reg_LPNI' AND site_applicable=mysite INTO sea_reg_lpn;

                IF(sea_block_status=1)THEN/*check if card is blocked by seasonal card manager*/
                    SET event='SPECIAL';

                    INSERT INTO bsc_attempts(`card_no`,`trans_date`,`station_name`,`lane_name`,`stationid`,bsc_description)VALUES
                    (_cardno,NOW(),stn_name,_lane,_station,'BLOCKED');

                    SET bool_code='FALSE';
                    SET error_code='ER244';
                    SET info_msg='MS246';               

                ELSE/*card not blocked by seasonal card manager*/
                    IF(NOW() > sea_validto)THEN/*is this card expired*/

                        INSERT INTO bsc_attempts(`card_no`,`trans_date`,`station_name`,`lane_name`,`stationid`,bsc_description)VALUES
                        (_cardno,NOW(),stn_name,_lane,_station,'EXPIRED');

                        SET bool_code='FALSE';
                        SET error_code='ER247';
                        SET info_msg='MS247';
                        SET event='SEASON';             

                    ELSE/*card not expired*/

                        IF(stn_type='ENTRY')THEN/*CHECK EVENT BY STATION TYPE*/
                            SET event='SEASON';


                            IF(ISNULL(sea_lpn))THEN SET sea_lpn='xxxx'; END IF;
                            #select sea_reg_lpn,sea_lpn,_lpn,CHAR_LENGTH(_lpn);                         


                            SELECT `trans_id`,`trans_date`,`in_out` FROM sea_card_transactions WHERE trans_id=(SELECT MAX(trans_id) FROM sea_card_transactions WHERE card_no=_cardno AND site_no=mysite) INTO tea_exists,op_date,location;
                            IF(CHAR_LENGTH(_lpn)>=7 && _lpn!= sea_lpn && sea_reg_lpn=1)THEN

                                    SET bool_code='FALSE';
                                    SET error_code='ER218';
                                    SET info_msg='MS218';

                                    INSERT INTO numberplate_mismatches(`token_number`,`token_type`,`entry_plates`,`exit_plates`,`ptrans_id`,action_description) VALUES
                                    (_cardno,'S-ACARD',ent_lpn,_lpn,tea_exists,'Seasonal Card mismatched and Blocked at Entry');




                            ELSE/*if that condition is not satisfied.tuendelee*/
                            #select tea_exists;
                                /*Lest check if there is a mismatch without blocking*/

                                SET event='SEASON';


                                IF(CHAR_LENGTH(_lpn)>=7 && _lpn!= sea_lpn)THEN

                                    INSERT INTO numberplate_mismatches(`token_number`,`token_type`,`entry_plates`,`exit_plates`,`ptrans_id`,action_description) VALUES
                                    (_cardno,'S-ACARD',ent_lpn,_lpn,tea_exists,'Seasonal Card mismatched but Allowed at Entry');                                

                                END IF;

                                /*end mismatch*/
                                IF(ISNULL(tea_exists) OR (location=0) OR (location=1 && DATE(NOW())>op_date))THEN/*allow entry*/

                                    IF(tea_exists>1 && location=1)THEN UPDATE sea_card_transactions SET in_out=0,exitdate=NOW() WHERE trans_id=tea_exists AND card_no=_cardno AND site_no=mysite; END IF;

                                    INSERT INTO sea_card_transactions(`card_no`,`trans_date`,`instation`,`entrygate`,`in_out`,`site_no`,entrydate,ass_lpn)VALUES
                                                    (_cardno,CURRENT_DATE,_station,stn_name,'1',mysite,NOW(),_lpn);

                                    SET bool_code='TRUE';
                                    SET error_code='ER000';
                                    SET info_msg='MS250';

                                ELSE

                                    SET bool_code='FALSE';
                                    SET error_code='ER249';
                                    SET info_msg='MS249';


                                END IF;                 


                            END IF;/*end chacking plates where plate chack setting is enforced*/

                        ELSEIF(stn_type='EXIT')THEN

                            SET event='SEASON';

                            IF(ISNULL(sea_lpn))THEN SET sea_lpn='xxxxxxx'; END IF;
                            #select sea_reg_lpn,sea_lpn,_lpn,CHAR_LENGTH(_lpn);                     
                            SELECT `trans_id`,`trans_date`,`in_out`,IFNULL(ass_lpn,'XXXXXX') FROM sea_card_transactions WHERE trans_id=(SELECT MAX(trans_id) FROM sea_card_transactions WHERE card_no=_cardno AND site_no=mysite) INTO tea_exists,op_date,location,ent_lpn;
                            #select sea_lpn;
                            IF(CHAR_LENGTH(_lpn)>=7 && (_lpn!= sea_lpn OR _lpn != ent_lpn) && (sea_reg_lpn=1 OR sea_ent_lpn=1))THEN/*is lnn check enforce*/

                                    SET bool_code='FALSE';
                                    SET error_code='ER218';
                                    SET info_msg='MS218';

                                    INSERT INTO numberplate_mismatches(`token_number`,`token_type`,`entry_plates`,`exit_plates`,`ptrans_id`,action_description) VALUES
                                        (_cardno,'S-ACARD',sea_lpn,_lpn,tea_exists,'Seasonal Card mismatched and Blocked at Exit');                             

                            ELSE

                                IF(CHAR_LENGTH(_lpn)>=7 && _lpn!= sea_lpn)THEN

                                    INSERT INTO numberplate_mismatches(`token_number`,`token_type`,`entry_plates`,`exit_plates`,`ptrans_id`,action_description) VALUES
                                    (_cardno,'S-ACARD',ent_lpn,_lpn,tea_exists,'Seasonal Card mismatched but allowed at Exit');                             

                                END IF;

                                IF(location=1)THEN

                                    UPDATE sea_card_transactions SET in_out=0,exitdate=NOW(),exitgate=stn_name,outstation=_station,ass_lpn=_lpn WHERE trans_id=tea_exists AND card_no=_cardno AND site_no=mysite;

                                    SET bool_code='TRUE';
                                    SET error_code='ER000';
                                    SET info_msg='MS220';        

                                ELSE

                                    SET bool_code='FALSE';
                                    SET error_code='ER221';
                                    SET info_msg='MS221';


                                END IF;                     

                            END IF;
                        ELSE            

                            SET bool_code='FALSE';
                            SET error_code='ER248';
                            SET info_msg='MS248';                       

                        END IF;                 

                    END IF;/*end expiry check*/             

                END IF;/*end check of seasonal blocked check*/

            ELSE/*normal card check */
                IF(stn_type='ENTRY')THEN                

                    SET event='ENTRY';

                    SELECT SQL_CACHE setting_validity FROM global_settings WHERE setting_name='sarit_apb_average' AND site_applicable=mysite LIMIT 1 INTO sarit_apb;
                    SELECT SQL_CACHE setting_validity FROM global_settings WHERE setting_name='confirm_acard_record' AND site_applicable=mysite LIMIT 1 INTO confirm_insert;
                    SELECT SQL_CACHE setting_value,setting_validity FROM global_settings WHERE setting_name='confirm_acard_balance' AND site_applicable=mysite LIMIT 1 INTO min_entry_bal,check_entry_bal;



                    #SELECT transid,in_out,entry_timestamp FROM parkingtrans WHERE transid=(SELECT MAX(transid) FROM parkingtrans WHERE card_no=_cardno AND transactiontype=(2,7)) INTO sea_exists,location,time_in;                            
                    #evans. 7:12 10/22/2015
                    SELECT transid,in_out,entry_timestamp FROM parkingtrans WHERE transid=(SELECT MAX(transid) FROM parkingtrans WHERE card_no=_cardno AND transactiontype IN(2,7)) INTO sea_exists,location,time_in;

                    IF check_entry_bal=1 &&  min_entry_bal> _baloncard  THEN

                            SET bool_code='FALSE';
                            SET error_code='ER243';
                            SET info_msg='MS243';



                    ELSEIF ISNULL(sea_exists) OR (sea_exists>=1 && location=0) OR (sea_exists>=1 && location=1 && sarit_apb=1 && DATE(time_in)< CURRENT_DATE) THEN/*card is good to enter*/
                        SET ent_dex="FULL ACARD ENTRY";
                        SET useful_transtype=2;
                        SELECT NOW() INTO time_in;

                        IF (sea_exists>=1 && location=1 && sarit_apb=1 && DATE(time_in)< CURRENT_DATE) THEN

                            SELECT IFNULL(crypt_key,'4545') FROM cryptonium WHERE site_no=mysite AND encrypt_start < NOW() AND (ISNULL(encrypt_end) OR encrypt_end > NOW()) INTO pass_key;
                            SELECT IFNULL(pass_key,'4545') INTO pass_key;

                            SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(0,pass_key) INTO char_amount;

                            SET useful_transtype=7;

                            UPDATE parkingtrans SET `transactiontype`=8,`in_out`=0,`bal_bf_exit`=_baloncard,`bal_af_exit`=_baloncard,
                            `trans_duration`=TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,time_in,CONCAT(time_in,':','23:59:59')),`amount_payable`=char_amount,`amount_paid`=char_amount,
                            `payment_status`=1,`pay_type`=1,`pay_activity`=0,`trans_year`=YEAR(NOW()),`trans_month`=MONTH(NOW()),`trans_date`=DATE(NOW()),`shift`='SHIFT1',
                            `paid_on`=NOW(),`pay_station`=_station,`site_no`=mysite,`exit_date`=DATE(NOW()),`exit_timestamp`=NOW() WHERE transid=sea_exists;

                        END IF;

                         SET ent_dex=ent_dex;

                        INSERT INTO `parkingtrans` (`entry_gate`, `entry_timestamp`, `datein`, `timein`, `hour_in`, `card_no`,`transactiontype`, `in_out`, `car_reg`, `face_capture`,lpn_capture, `device_no`, `veh_class`,`token_site_zone`,`site_no`,`bal_on_entry`,entry_description) VALUES
                                                   (stn_name,time_in,DATE(time_in),TIME(time_in),HOUR(time_in),_cardno,useful_transtype,1,_lpn,_fimagepath,_limagepath,ent_device,IFNULL(_vehcat,1),myzone,mysite,_baloncard,ent_dex);


                         SET ent_dex=ent_dex;

                         IF confirm_insert=1 THEN

                            SELECT transid FROM parkingtrans WHERE card_no=_cardno AND transactiontype=2 AND token_site_zone=myzone AND entry_timestamp=time_in LIMIT 1 INTO newest_record_id;
                            #select newest_record_id;
                            IF ISNULL(newest_record_id) THEN

                                SELECT CONCAT(ent_dex,' RETRY') INTO ent_dex; 

                                INSERT INTO `parkingtrans` (`entry_gate`, `entry_timestamp`, `datein`, `timein`, `hour_in`, `card_no`,`transactiontype`, `in_out`, `car_reg`, `face_capture`,lpn_capture, `device_no`, `veh_class`,`token_site_zone`,`site_no`,`bal_on_entry`,entry_description) VALUES
                                                    (stn_name,time_in,DATE(time_in),TIME(time_in),HOUR(time_in),_cardno,useful_transtype,1,_lpn,_fimagepath,_limagepath,ent_device,IFNULL(_vehcat,1),myzone,mysite,_baloncard,ent_dex);


                            END IF;                 


                        END IF;

                        SET lastinsert=LAST_INSERT_ID();                         

                        SET bool_code='TRUE';
                        SET error_code='ER000';
                        SET info_msg='MS250';

                    ELSE/*card has APB*/                    

                        SET bool_code='FALSE';
                        SET error_code='ER249';
                        SET info_msg='MS249';           


                    END IF;


                ELSEIF(stn_type='EXIT')THEN

                    SET event='EXIT';

                    SELECT SQL_CACHE setting_validity FROM global_settings WHERE setting_name='normal_LPNI' AND site_applicable=mysite INTO sea_ent_lpn;

                    SELECT SQL_CACHE setting_validity FROM global_settings WHERE setting_name='sarit_apb_average' AND site_applicable=mysite LIMIT 1 INTO sarit_apb;

                    SELECT SQL_CACHE setting_validity FROM global_settings WHERE setting_name='pay_by_entry_zone' AND site_applicable=mysite LIMIT 1 INTO use_entry_zone;       


                    SELECT NOW() INTO time_now;

                    #select sea_ent_lpn,sarit_apb,use_entry_zone;

                    SELECT get_current_shift(_station,time_now) INTO shift_string;              
                    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(shift_string,'#',2),'#',-1) INTO myshift;

                    /*SELECT IFNULL(crypt_key,'4545') FROM cryptonium WHERE site_no=mysite AND encrypt_start < NOW() AND (ISNULL(encrypt_end) OR encrypt_end > NOW()) INTO pass_key;*/

                    SELECT transid,in_out,entry_timestamp,car_reg,`payment_status`,`pay_activity`,entry_description,trans_description,token_site_zone,transactiontype FROM parkingtrans WHERE transid=(SELECT MAX(transid) FROM parkingtrans
                    WHERE card_no=_cardno AND transactiontype IN(2,7)) INTO sea_exists,location,time_in,ent_lpn,pay_state,lipa_activity,acq_entry_dex,acq_trans_dex,entry_zone,card_trans_type; 

                    IF(ISNULL(sea_exists) OR location=0)THEN

                        SET return_value=0;                 
                        SET bool_code='FALSE';
                        SET error_code='ER221';
                        SET info_msg='MS221';           

                    ELSE
                        IF sea_ent_lpn=1 && ent_lpn>5 && ent_lpn != 'AIG400K' && CHAR_LENGTH(_lpn)>=7 && ent_lpn != _lpn THEN/*validate detected license plate at exit*/

                                SET return_value=0;                 
                                SET bool_code='FALSE';
                                SET error_code='ER218';
                                SET info_msg='MS218';

                                INSERT INTO numberplate_mismatches(`token_number`,`token_type`,`entry_plates`,`exit_plates`,`ptrans_id`,action_descritpion) VALUES
                                (_cardno,'N-ACARD',ent_lpn,_lpn,sea_exists,'Normal Card mismatched and Blocked at Exit');                           

                        ELSE

                            /*Lets log mismatches even if there is not blockage*/
                            IF ent_lpn>5 && ent_lpn != 'AIG400K' && CHAR_LENGTH(_lpn)>=7 && ent_lpn != _lpn THEN

                                INSERT INTO numberplate_mismatches(`token_number`,`token_type`,`entry_plates`,`exit_plates`,`ptrans_id`,action_descritpion) VALUES
                                (_cardno,'N-ACARD',ent_lpn,_lpn,sea_exists,'Normal Card mismatched but Allowed Out at Exit');


                            END IF;

                            /*Lets calculate a charge if sarit_apb is enacted*/

                            IF sarit_apb=1 AND card_trans_type=7 THEN                           

                                SELECT AVG(sarit.afrage) FROM  (SELECT trans_amount AS afrage FROM acardtransactions WHERE trans_type=2 AND card_no=_cardno  ORDER BY trans_id DESC LIMIT 2,5) AS sarit INTO sarit_avg_amt;

                                SELECT FLOOR(sarit_avg_amt) INTO sarit_avg_amt;

                            END IF;



                            /*enuf*/

                            /*Hallo*/
                            IF use_entry_zone=1 THEN

                                SET myzone=entry_zone;

                            END IF;
                            /*lets charge*/

                            SELECT FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,time_in,time_now)) INTO raw_duration;

                            IF raw_duration > 1440 THEN
                                SELECT FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,time_in,time_now)) INTO days_spent;

                                /*We check for the day rates aggressively*/
                                SELECT fullday_rate_sniffer(time_in,myzone,_vehcat,days_spent,mysite) INTO fd_fee;


                                SELECT DATE_ADD(time_in, INTERVAL days_spent DAY) INTO time_in;/*get our new time in*/                                          

                                SET fd_fee=fd_fee*days_spent;                               
                                IF ISNULL(fd_fee)THEN SET fd_fee=0; END IF;#safety
                            END IF;

                            /*Lets now calculate the amount time spent on a single day*/
                            SELECT DAYOFWEEK(time_in) INTO dow1;
                            SELECT DAYOFWEEK(time_now) INTO dow2;

                            IF(dow1 != dow2) THEN
                                #SELECT myzone,dow1,_vehcat,time_in,CONCAT(DATE(time_in),' ','23:59:59');
                                 SELECT rate_sniffer(myzone,dow1,_vehcat,time_in,CONCAT(DATE(time_in),' ','23:59:59'),'A') INTO fee1;

                                 #SELECT myzone,dow2,_vehcat,CONCAT(DATE(time_now),' ','00:00:00'),time_now;                   
                                 SELECT rate_sniffer(myzone,dow2,_vehcat,CONCAT(DATE(time_now),' ','00:00:00'),time_now,'B') INTO fee2;  

                            ELSE        
                                #SELECT myzone,dow1,_vehcat,time_in,time_now;
                                SELECT rate_sniffer(myzone,dow1,_vehcat,time_in,time_now,'A') INTO fee1;

                            END IF;



                            SET total_fee=IFNULL(fd_fee,0)+IFNULL(fee1,0)+IFNULL(fee2,0);



                            IF location=1 && pay_state>=1 THEN

                                SELECT `get_partial_total`(_cardno,'',mysite) INTO amount_charged;

                                SET total_fee=total_fee-IFNULL(amount_charged,0); 

                            END IF;

                            SET total_fee=total_fee+IFNULL(sarit_avg_amt,0);                        


                            IF total_fee > _baloncard THEN

                                SET return_value=total_fee;                 
                                SET bool_code='FALSE';
                                SET error_code='ER243';
                                SET info_msg='MS243';                           

                            ELSE

                                SELECT trans_id FROM acardtransactions WHERE parkingtrans_transid=sea_exists AND card_no=_cardno AND DATE(time_in)=DATE(time_in) LIMIT 0,1 INTO cardrec;

                                IF ISNULL(cardrec) THEN

                                    INSERT INTO `acardtransactions` (`parkingtrans_transid`, `card_no`, `trans_time`, `timein`, `timeout`, `amount_before`, `expected_amount`,`trans_station`, `merchant_id`, `site`, `trans_type`, `trans_desc`,logged) VALUES
                                                          (sea_exists,_cardno,time_now,time_in,time_now,_baloncard,total_fee,_station,merch_agent,mysite,2,'EXIT CHARGE',3);
                                 END IF;

                                SET return_value=total_fee;                 
                                SET bool_code='TRUE';
                                SET error_code='ER000';
                                SET info_msg='MS000';

                            END IF;                                                 

                        END IF ;                                            

                    END IF;             

                ELSE                

                    SET bool_code='FALSE';
                    SET error_code='ER248';
                    SET info_msg='MS248';               

                END IF;/*Normal Exit Event Check*/



            END IF;/*end of seasonal or normal check*/  

        END IF;/*end of blacklist check*/

    END IF;/*end of master or blocked check*/
END IF;/*end of parameter check*/
   /*lets check pending details*/
   SELECT floating_value,floating_status,fid FROM floating_acard WHERE card_no=_cardno AND floating_status=1 INTO pending_value,pending,pending_id;

    IF pending_id >=1 THEN

    SET pending_value=IFNULL(return_value,0)-IFNULL(pending_value,0);

    ELSE

    SET pending_value=return_value;

    END IF; 


   SELECT disp_msg(info_msg) INTO message_string;   

   SELECT CONCAT(_cardno,' @ ', NOW(),' @ ',stn_type,' last-record:',IFNULL(lastinsert,0)) INTO story;

   SELECT get_severity(error_code) INTO error_sev;

   SELECT bool_code,error_code,info_msg,message_string,IFNULL(return_value,0) AS return_value,stn_type,IFNULL(pending_value,0) AS pending_value,pending,IFNULL(pending_id,'') AS pending_id,event,story;





END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Use of transactions in this and other produres did the magic.